# Hide caret in WPF TextBox

Tags: wpf, textbox, text-cursor

Is there a way to hide the cursor in a WPF textbox? I know there is Cursor="None" but that only affects the mouse cursor. I want to hide the "text cursor".

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935769/wpf-passwordbox-caret

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Caret is the current insert position in a text editor.  Cursor is the shape of the mouse cursor.

There is no way to disable the caret in a read-write TextBox.  Instead, change the CaretBrush to be transparent.

```
TextBox txt = ...;
// Hide the caret.
txt.CaretBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
// Show the caret.
txt.CaretBrush = null;  // use default Brush
```

Comment: Awesome! I sought through the web. This question has been asked very often. The amswers are mostly nonsense or no-use.

Answer (score 15):

You can colour the cursor the same colour as the background or `Transparent` using the `TextBox.CaretBrush` property.